# line 5747 in swift Foundation is" public typealias ObservableObject = ObservableObject " why?

Tags: swift

[image]

```
public typealias ObservableObject = ObservableObject
```

Why is this seemingly pointless type alias here?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the actual code for this `typealias` in the swift-corelibs-foundation repository (where the Swift Foundation overlay lives alongside the open-source rewrite in Swift) [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/CombineTypealiases.swift#L21):

```swift
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public typealias ObservableObject = Combine.ObservableObject
```

It's like @Sweeper already mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68934171/1388842). Foundation exports a type from Combine this way, so that you can `import Foundation` and still have access to `ObservableObject` (without an explicit `import Combine`).

Comment: I did not expect the Foundation source code to be open source! TIL.

Comment: The Swift overlay over Darwin Foundation is open source, yes. Also the Swift rewrite of Foundation (mainly used with Linux) is open source. Most of the implementation that you use when using Foundation is still in Objective-C and thus closed source, though.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the file that you are looking at is part of the `Foundation` framework, *not* Combine. The purpose of the type alias is to make the `ObservableObject` protocol available, even if you've only imported `Foundation` but not `Combine`. In short, this saves some keystrokes.

See the documentation for this type alias [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/observableobject). As you can see, it says that this type alias is in "Foundation", and it is a type alias for the protocol in Combine:

[image]

Also note that there is a similar type alias for the [`@Published`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/published) property wrapper, because if you are using `ObservableObject`s, you are going to use `@Publisher` as well.